# Finding Unique Users When Changing Info

Tags: r, igraph

I have the following data:

```
dat <- data.frame(user_id = c(101,102,102,103,103,106),
           phone_number = c(4030201, 4030201, 4030202, 4030202, 4030203, 4030204))
```

I want to calculate the unique users. As you can see, here we have 2 unique users. So, ultimately the table I want to create is the following:

```
user_id    phone_number    new_user_id 
    101         4030201              1
    102         4030201              1  
    102         4030202              1
    103         4030202              1
    103         4030203              1
    106         4030204              2
```

Any ideas on how could I calculate this in R? Or in a different language and then I can translate the code to R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated02** (Some minor tweaks needed to be made)
I had to ask two questions to be able to solve it. If you are dealing with this kind of questions a lot, you are required to learn `igraph` package which is primarily used for network analysis. There maybe a more simple way of doing it but for now I think it will do. Let's walk you through it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# In the firs chunk we iterate over every row of your data set to find out
# whether there is a connection between the corresponding rows and the others

map(1:nrow(dat), function(x) {
  dat %>%
    mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
    pmap_lgl(., ~ {x <- unlist(dat[x,]); 
    any(x %in% c(...))})
}) %>%
  exec(cbind, !!!.) %>%
  as.data.frame() -> dat2

dat2 %>%
  pmap(~ sub("V", "", names(dat2))[c(...)] %>% as.numeric()) -> ids

[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 2 3 4

[[4]]
[1] 3 4 5

[[5]]
[1] 4 5 8

[[6]]
[1] 6

[[7]]
[1] 7

[[8]]
[1] 5 8
```

Then we group all the related `id`s together. For this part I used [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67967361/finding-actual-unique-users-when-they-change-their-details-user-ids-or-phone-nu/67967563?noredirect=1#comment120160487_67967563) proposed by my dear friends @det & @Ian Campbell cause I don't know how to use `igraph`.

```
library(igraph)

map(ids, function(a) map_int(ids, ~length(base::intersect(a, .x)) > 0) * 1L) %>% 
  reduce(rbind) %>%
  graph.adjacency() %>%
  as.undirected() %>%
  components() %>%
  pluck("membership") %>%
  split(seq_along(.), .) %>%
  map(~unique(unlist(ids[.x]))) -> grouped_ids

$`1`
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 8

$`2`
[1] 6

$`3`
[1] 7
```

After we grouped all the related once together, we can then group our data set:

```
dat %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(grp = seq(length(grouped_ids))[map_lgl(grouped_ids, ~ id %in% .x)])

  user_id phone_number id grp
1     101      4030201  1   1
2     102      4030201  2   1
3     102      4030202  3   1
4     103      4030202  4   1
5     103      4030203  5   1
6     106      4030204  6   2
7     107      4030205  7   3
8     111      4030203  8   1
```

**Data**

```
structure(list(user_id = c(101, 102, 102, 103, 103, 106, 107, 
111), phone_number = c(4030201, 4030201, 4030202, 4030202, 4030203, 
4030204, 4030205, 4030203)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: If we add user_id: 104 and phone_number: 4030203 to our data, it doesn't detect this user as the same. Also, if we add user_id: 107 and phone_number: 4030205, it doesn't detect this user as a new one.

Comment: @JamesHarrington check my updates again please.

Comment: check for this data
dat <- data.frame(user_id = c(101,102,102,103,103,106,107,111),
                  phone_number = c(4030201, 4030201, 4030202, 4030202, 4030203, 4030204, 4030205, 4030203))

Comment: This is amazing, I should really study this. Thanks a mil!

Comment: Oh my pleasure. Have you tried it on your complete data set? if so was the output what your were looking for?

Comment: By the way my friend's answer is much shorter, at the time I wrote it I didn't know `igraph` could efficiently detect all edges for us. So I will leave mine as is and his is also there you could use both.

Comment: Neat that you used the other questions to solve this one.

Comment: Thank you very much dear @IanCampbell . It was interesting actually as I created all the edges but didn't know how to group them, but apparently as my friend's answer shows `graph.data.frame` would also create it from the original data set. It may seem to have some unnecessary steps but I left it as is so everyone's contributions would be distinct and recognized.

Comment: @JamesHarrington It can definitely be modified, it just needs some modifications ,but I suggest in order to have more asuitable solution you ask another question by providing a data sample that best represents every possible situation like the one you provided in comments.

Comment: Sure did. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Simplifying my friend's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67967563/2884859) a bit

```r
dat <- data.frame(user_id = c(101,102,102,103,103,106),
                  phone_number = c(4030201, 4030201, 4030202, 4030202, 4030203, 4030204))

library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)

graph.data.frame(dat) %>%
  components() %>%
  pluck(membership) %>%
  stack() %>%
  set_names(c('GRP', 'user_id')) %>%
  right_join(dat %>% mutate(user_id = as.factor(user_id)), by = c('user_id'))

  GRP user_id phone_number
1   1     101      4030201
2   1     102      4030201
3   1     102      4030202
4   1     103      4030202
5   1     103      4030203
6   2     106      4030204
```

---

on `dat` given in comments, it gives

```
  GRP user_id phone_number
1   1     101      4030201
2   1     102      4030201
3   1     102      4030202
4   1     103      4030202
5   1     103      4030203
6   2     106      4030204
7   3     107      4030205
8   1     111      4030203
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `igraph` option

```
dat %>%
    mutate(new_user_id = membership(components(graph_from_data_frame(.)))[as.character(user_id)])
```

which gives

```
  user_id phone_number new_user_id
1     101      4030201           1
2     102      4030201           1
3     102      4030202           1
4     103      4030202           1
5     103      4030203           1
6     106      4030204           2
```