# How to do network analysis on three fields simultaneously in R

Tags: r, igraph, network-analysis

How can I do a network analysis on three fields simultaneously in R.  Below is sample data along with `desired output` in last column.

```r
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                    id_1 = c("ABC","ABC","BCD",
                             "CDE","DEF","EFG","GHI","HIJ","IJK","JKL",
                             "GHI","KLM","LMN","MNO","NOP"),
                    id_2 = c("1A","2A","3A",
                             "1A","4A","5A","6A","8A","9A","10A","7A",
                             "12A","13A","14A","15A"),
                    id_3 = c("Z3","Z2","Z1",
                             "Z4","Z1","Z5","Z5","Z6","Z7","Z8","Z6","Z8",
                             "Z9","Z9","Z1"),
                    Name = c("StackOverflow1",
                             "StackOverflow2","StackOverflow3","StackOverflow4",
                             "StackOverflow5","StackOverflow6",
                             "StackOverflow7","StackOverflow8","StackOverflow9",
                             "StackOverflow10","StackOverflow11","StackOverflow12",
                             "StackOverflow13","StackOverflow14","StackOverflow15"),
          desired_output = c(1L,1L,2L,1L,2L,
                             3L,3L,3L,4L,5L,3L,5L,6L,6L,2L)
      )
df
#>    id_1 id_2 id_3            Name desired_output
#> 1   ABC   1A   Z3  StackOverflow1              1
#> 2   ABC   2A   Z2  StackOverflow2              1
#> 3   BCD   3A   Z1  StackOverflow3              2
#> 4   CDE   1A   Z4  StackOverflow4              1
#> 5   DEF   4A   Z1  StackOverflow5              2
#> 6   EFG   5A   Z5  StackOverflow6              3
#> 7   GHI   6A   Z5  StackOverflow7              3
#> 8   HIJ   8A   Z6  StackOverflow8              3
#> 9   IJK   9A   Z7  StackOverflow9              4
#> 10  JKL  10A   Z8 StackOverflow10              5
#> 11  GHI   7A   Z6 StackOverflow11              3
#> 12  KLM  12A   Z8 StackOverflow12              5
#> 13  LMN  13A   Z9 StackOverflow13              6
#> 14  MNO  14A   Z9 StackOverflow14              6
#> 15  NOP  15A   Z1 StackOverflow15              2
```

Actually I can perform network analysis on 2 fields simultaneously using `igraph` as described in my own answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67973872/2884859), but I am unable to do it on 2 fields.

Please help.

My present approach (2 iterations), Which I have a feeling can be optimised.

```r
library(igraph)
library(tidyverse)

graph.data.frame(df) %>%
  components() %>%
  pluck(membership) %>%
  stack() %>%
  set_names(c('GRP', 'id_1')) %>%
  right_join(df %>% mutate(id_1 = as.factor(id_1)), by = c('id_1')) %>%
  select(GRP, id_3) %>%
  graph.data.frame() %>% 
  components() %>%
  pluck(membership) %>%
  stack() %>%
  set_names(c('GRP', 'id_3')) %>%
  right_join(df %>% mutate(id_3 = as.factor(id_3)), by = c('id_3'))
#>    GRP id_3 id_1 id_2            Name desired_output
#> 1    1   Z3  ABC   1A  StackOverflow1              1
#> 2    1   Z2  ABC   2A  StackOverflow2              1
#> 3    2   Z1  BCD   3A  StackOverflow3              2
#> 4    2   Z1  DEF   4A  StackOverflow5              2
#> 5    2   Z1  NOP  15A StackOverflow15              2
#> 6    1   Z4  CDE   1A  StackOverflow4              1
#> 7    3   Z5  EFG   5A  StackOverflow6              3
#> 8    3   Z5  GHI   6A  StackOverflow7              3
#> 9    3   Z6  HIJ   8A  StackOverflow8              3
#> 10   3   Z6  GHI   7A StackOverflow11              3
#> 11   4   Z7  IJK   9A  StackOverflow9              4
#> 12   5   Z8  JKL  10A StackOverflow10              5
#> 13   5   Z8  KLM  12A StackOverflow12              5
#> 14   6   Z9  LMN  13A StackOverflow13              6
#> 15   6   Z9  MNO  14A StackOverflow14              6
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create list of all connections between vertices defined by id columns and row number (function `f`). At the end you are interested only in connection between rows.

```
f <- function(vec){
  
  i <- last(vec)
  vec <- head(vec, -1)
  
  c(
    seq_len(length(vec) - 1) %>% map(~vec[.x:(.x+1)]),
    vec %>% map(~c(i, .x))
  ) 
}

df$desired_output <- df %>%
  select(matches("^id_[0-9]+$")) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pmap(~f(c(...))) %>%
  flatten() %>%
  reduce(rbind) %>%
  igraph::graph_from_edgelist() %>% 
  components() %>%
  membership() %>%
  .[as.character(seq_len(nrow(df)))]
```

**edit**

Imagine connections between ids. You are interested in connections between rows. For that you need to add vertices for each row. Those vertices are connected to all ids in that row.

Example for 6th row:

```
6  EFG   5A   Z5
```

we are interested in connections between ids (first part in `c` in function `f`:

```
[[1]]
[1] "EFG" "5A" 

[[2]]
[1] "5A" "Z5"
```

and connections between row and ids (second part of `c` in `f`):

```
[[1]]
[1] "6"   "EFG"

[[2]]
[1] "6"  "5A"

[[3]]
[1] "6"  "Z5"
```

when you create graph that way you end up with:

[image]

and you are interested which row vertices are connected

**note**

you can use `directed = FALSE` when creating graph for this result, or `mode = "strong"` in `components` if you are interested in that.

Comment: Fabulous!  can you please explain a bit more of the custom function syntax?

Comment: I've add edit. hopefully its more clear what the goal is.

Comment: Thanks it is clear, But I am trying to understand custom function `f`

Comment: I've added example. Goal of that function is to define connections in graph for each row of `df`

Comment: Thanks. Please also have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69986682/2884859)

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Solution**
In case of only getting the desired column it could be another alternative:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(igraph)

df %>%
  select(starts_with("id")) %>%
  pmap_dfr(~ as.data.frame(t(combn(c(...), 2)))) %>%
  graph_from_data_frame(directed = TRUE) %>%
  components() %>% 
  groups() -> lst
  
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(grp = seq_len(length(lst))[map_lgl(lst, ~ id_1 %in% .x)])

# A tibble: 15 x 5
# Rowwise: 
   id_1  id_2  id_3  Name              grp
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>           <int>
 1 ABC   1A    Z3    StackOverflow1      1
 2 ABC   2A    Z2    StackOverflow2      1
 3 BCD   3A    Z1    StackOverflow3      2
 4 CDE   1A    Z4    StackOverflow4      1
 5 DEF   4A    Z1    StackOverflow5      2
 6 EFG   5A    Z5    StackOverflow6      3
 7 GHI   6A    Z5    StackOverflow7      3
 8 HIJ   8A    Z6    StackOverflow8      3
 9 IJK   9A    Z7    StackOverflow9      4
10 JKL   10A   Z8    StackOverflow10     5
11 GHI   7A    Z6    StackOverflow11     3
12 KLM   12A   Z8    StackOverflow12     5
13 LMN   13A   Z9    StackOverflow13     6
14 MNO   14A   Z9    StackOverflow14     6
15 NOP   15A   Z1    StackOverflow15     2
```

In order for you just to plot it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(igraph)

df %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  select(starts_with("id"), id) %>%
  pmap_dfr(~ as.data.frame(t(combn(c(...), 2)))) %>%
  graph_from_data_frame(directed = TRUE) %>%
  plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Please also have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69986682/2884859)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the code below

```
transform(
  df,
  GRP = membership(
    components(
      graph_from_data_frame(
        reshape(
          df,
          direction = "long",
          idvar = c("id_1", "Name"),
          varying = 2:3,
          v.names = "to"
        )[c("id_1", "to")]
      )
    )
  )[id_1]
)
```

which gives

```
   id_1 id_2 id_3            Name GRP
1   ABC   1A   Z3  StackOverflow1   1
2   ABC   2A   Z2  StackOverflow2   1
3   BCD   3A   Z1  StackOverflow3   2
4   CDE   1A   Z4  StackOverflow4   1
5   DEF   4A   Z1  StackOverflow5   2
6   EFG   5A   Z5  StackOverflow6   3
7   GHI   6A   Z5  StackOverflow7   3
8   HIJ   8A   Z6  StackOverflow8   3
9   IJK   9A   Z7  StackOverflow9   4
10  JKL  10A   Z8 StackOverflow10   5
11  GHI   7A   Z6 StackOverflow11   3
12  KLM  12A   Z8 StackOverflow12   5
13  LMN  13A   Z9 StackOverflow13   6
14  MNO  14A   Z9 StackOverflow14   6
15  NOP  15A   Z1 StackOverflow15   2
```

## Data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(id_1 = c("ABC", "ABC", "BCD", "CDE", "DEF", "EFG", 
"GHI", "HIJ", "IJK", "JKL", "GHI", "KLM", "LMN", "MNO", "NOP"
), id_2 = c("1A", "2A", "3A", "1A", "4A", "5A", "6A", "8A", "9A",
"10A", "7A", "12A", "13A", "14A", "15A"), id_3 = c("Z3", "Z2",
"Z1", "Z4", "Z1", "Z5", "Z5", "Z6", "Z7", "Z8", "Z6", "Z8", "Z9",
"Z9", "Z1"), Name = c("StackOverflow1", "StackOverflow2", "StackOverflow3",
"StackOverflow4", "StackOverflow5", "StackOverflow6", "StackOverflow7",
"StackOverflow8", "StackOverflow9", "StackOverflow10", "StackOverflow11",
"StackOverflow12", "StackOverflow13", "StackOverflow14", "StackOverflow15"
)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hello Brother, so glad to see you here? I really enjoy network analysis and `igraph` :) I would like to start reading Gabor Csardi's book but cannot find time. But I will read your ports with great interest.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR glad that you play around `igraph` joyfully :)

Comment: Thanks. Please also have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69986682/2884859)

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Thank you very much, hope I will be as good as you one day.