# How to handle null values /NAs in network analysis

Tags: r, igraph, network-analysis

This question is basically extension of my previous question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69969772/how-to-do-network-analysis-on-three-fields-simultaneously-in-r/69980572#69980572).
How to handle null values/NAs in these types of situations.
Example scenario and data

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                    id_1 = c("ABC","ABC","BCD",
                             "CDE","DEF","EFG","GHI","HIJ","IJK","JKL",
                             "GHI","KLM","LMN","MNO","NOP"),
                    id_2 = c("1A","2A","3A",
                             "1A","4A","5A","6A",NA,"9A","10A","7A",
                             "12A","13A",NA,"15A"),
                    id_3 = c("Z3","Z2","Z1",
                             "Z4","Z1","Z5","Z5","Z6","Z7","Z8","Z6","Z8",
                             "Z9","Z9","Z1"),
                    Name = c("StackOverflow1",
                             "StackOverflow2","StackOverflow3","StackOverflow4",
                             "StackOverflow5","StackOverflow6",
                             "StackOverflow7","StackOverflow8","StackOverflow9",
                             "StackOverflow10","StackOverflow11","StackOverflow12",
                             "StackOverflow13","StackOverflow14","StackOverflow15"),
          desired_output = c(1L,1L,2L,1L,2L,
                             3L,3L,3L,4L,5L,3L,5L,6L,6L,2L)
      )

df1
   id_1 id_2 id_3            Name desired_output
1   ABC   1A   Z3  StackOverflow1              1
2   ABC   2A   Z2  StackOverflow2              1
3   BCD   3A   Z1  StackOverflow3              2
4   CDE   1A   Z4  StackOverflow4              1
5   DEF   4A   Z1  StackOverflow5              2
6   EFG   5A   Z5  StackOverflow6              3
7   GHI   6A   Z5  StackOverflow7              3
8   HIJ <NA>   Z6  StackOverflow8              3
9   IJK   9A   Z7  StackOverflow9              4
10  JKL  10A   Z8 StackOverflow10              5
11  GHI   7A   Z6 StackOverflow11              3
12  KLM  12A   Z8 StackOverflow12              5
13  LMN  13A   Z9 StackOverflow13              6
14  MNO <NA>   Z9 StackOverflow14              6
15  NOP  15A   Z1 StackOverflow15              2
```

But the three approaches suggested in the linked post are not working and giving me errors.

Please suggest.

Comment: You can first replace `NA` with character '"NA"', then I guess problem can be solved in the same way as in the previous question.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding that will link all records with text `NA` which I do not want!

Comment: Sorry, my bad. See my answer below.

Comment: Can you please explain the question in plain English in these cases? Neither this, nor your previous question is very clear. One has to do guesswork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Additional Notes**

In order to be able to cluster this network we need an edge list of `id`s. In this data frame we have in fact 3 `id`s in every row, indicating a sort of triad structure or in general it shows a connection between all three of them. So

- I first chose the 3 targeted variables, then I used `pmap` function to create every combination of length 2 between these 3 vertices and bound the results together row-wise
- In the next step we got to a data frame with only 2 variables which formed our required edge list that contained every existing edges between our original vertices (variables)]
- Then I used `tidyr::drop_na` to remove those missing values assuming that in a setting like `HIJ --- NA` we are only able to define the membership of `HIJ` if there is any edge between it and others vertices in other observations. So it is safe to remove them in the first code chunk
- In the end I extracted related components with `membership` function and also used `groups` to extract the clusters. Those clusters' id are where we extract our `desired_output` variable, how?
  Since every cluster is quite separated from the others we assume that every vertex or `id`s in the original data set can only be part of one cluster so we checked this by the second code chunk and I only checked `id_1` for this.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)

df1 %>%
  select(starts_with("id")) %>%
  pmap_dfr(~ as.data.frame(t(combn(c(...), 2)))) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  graph_from_data_frame(directed = TRUE) %>%
  components() %>% 
  groups() -> lst
  
df1 %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(grp = seq_len(length(lst))[map_lgl(lst, ~ id_1 %in% .x)])

# A tibble: 15 x 6
# Rowwise: 
   id_1  id_2  id_3  Name            desired_output   grp
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>                    <int> <int>
 1 ABC   1A    Z3    StackOverflow1               1     1
 2 ABC   2A    Z2    StackOverflow2               1     1
 3 BCD   3A    Z1    StackOverflow3               2     2
 4 CDE   1A    Z4    StackOverflow4               1     1
 5 DEF   4A    Z1    StackOverflow5               2     2
 6 EFG   5A    Z5    StackOverflow6               3     3
 7 GHI   6A    Z5    StackOverflow7               3     3
 8 HIJ   NA    Z6    StackOverflow8               3     3
 9 IJK   9A    Z7    StackOverflow9               4     4
10 JKL   10A   Z8    StackOverflow10              5     5
11 GHI   7A    Z6    StackOverflow11              3     3
12 KLM   12A   Z8    StackOverflow12              5     5
13 LMN   13A   Z9    StackOverflow13              6     6
14 MNO   NA    Z9    StackOverflow14              6     6
15 NOP   15A   Z1    StackOverflow15              2     2
```

Comment: Thanks @Anoushiravan For the answer.  Please add some more information on the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

## Update

If you have more then one `NA` in certain row, you can try the code below

```
transform(
  df,
  GRP = membership(
    components(
      graph_from_data_frame(
        transform(
          reshape(
            df,
            direction = "long",
            idvar = c("id_1", "Name"),
            varying = 2:3,
            v.names = "to"
          )[c("id_1", "to")],
          to = ifelse(is.na(to), id_1, to)
        )
      )
    )
  )[id_1]
)
```

which gives

```
   id_1 id_2 id_3            Name GRP
1   ABC   1A   Z3  StackOverflow1   1
2   ABC   2A   Z2  StackOverflow2   1
3   BCD   3A   Z1  StackOverflow3   2
4   CDE   1A   Z4  StackOverflow4   1
5   DEF   4A   Z1  StackOverflow5   2
6   EFG   5A   Z5  StackOverflow6   3
7   GHI   6A   Z5  StackOverflow7   3
8   HIJ <NA> <NA>  StackOverflow8   4
9   IJK   9A   Z7  StackOverflow9   5
10  JKL  10A   Z8 StackOverflow10   6
11  GHI   7A   Z6 StackOverflow11   3
12  KLM  12A   Z8 StackOverflow12   6
13  LMN  13A <NA> StackOverflow13   7
14  MNO <NA> <NA> StackOverflow14   8
15  NOP  15A   Z1 StackOverflow15   2
```

**Dummy Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(id_1 = c("ABC", "ABC", "BCD", "CDE", "DEF", "EFG", 
"GHI", "HIJ", "IJK", "JKL", "GHI", "KLM", "LMN", "MNO", "NOP"
), id_2 = c("1A", "2A", "3A", "1A", "4A", "5A", "6A", NA, "9A",
"10A", "7A", "12A", "13A", NA, "15A"), id_3 = c("Z3", "Z2", "Z1",
"Z4", "Z1", "Z5", "Z5", NA, "Z7", "Z8", "Z6", "Z8", NA, NA, "Z1"
), Name = c("StackOverflow1", "StackOverflow2", "StackOverflow3",
"StackOverflow4", "StackOverflow5", "StackOverflow6", "StackOverflow7",
"StackOverflow8", "StackOverflow9", "StackOverflow10", "StackOverflow11",
"StackOverflow12", "StackOverflow13", "StackOverflow14", "StackOverflow15"
)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

## Previous Answer

Maybe you can replace `NA` in column `id_2` by the values in `id_1`, and the follow the answers in previous questions.

You can try this

```
transform(
  df,
  GRP = membership(
    components(
      graph_from_data_frame(
        reshape(
          transform(
            df,
            id_2 = ifelse(is.na(id_2), id_1, id_2)
          ),
          direction = "long",
          idvar = c("id_1", "Name"),
          varying = 2:3,
          v.names = "to"
        )[c("id_1", "to")]
      )
    )
  )[id_1]
)
```

which gives

```
   id_1 id_2 id_3            Name GRP
1   ABC   1A   Z3  StackOverflow1   1
2   ABC   2A   Z2  StackOverflow2   1
3   BCD   3A   Z1  StackOverflow3   2
4   CDE   1A   Z4  StackOverflow4   1
5   DEF   4A   Z1  StackOverflow5   2
6   EFG   5A   Z5  StackOverflow6   3
7   GHI   6A   Z5  StackOverflow7   3
8   HIJ <NA>   Z6  StackOverflow8   3
9   IJK   9A   Z7  StackOverflow9   4
10  JKL  10A   Z8 StackOverflow10   5
11  GHI   7A   Z6 StackOverflow11   3
12  KLM  12A   Z8 StackOverflow12   5
13  LMN  13A   Z9 StackOverflow13   6
14  MNO <NA>   Z9 StackOverflow14   6
15  NOP  15A   Z1 StackOverflow15   2
```

Comment: Thanks.  But I think it works only at least one column has null values! What if some rows are having blank values in all id_columns?  can this be modified?

Comment: @AnilGoyal Could you generate a data as what you described? I will take a look

Comment: Thanks for your effort.  I am accepting another answer this time also, but I will post another question with more specific database sample.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `NA`:

```
df$desired_output <- df %>%
  select(matches("^id_[0-9]+$")) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pmap(~c(...) %>% .[!is.na(.)]) %>%
  map(f) %>%
  flatten() %>%
  reduce(rbind) %>%
  igraph::graph_from_edgelist() %>% 
  components() %>%
  membership() %>%
  .[as.character(seq_len(nrow(df)))]
```

Comment: Thanks @det for your answer.  Already upvoted.  Accepting another answer this time.